# Google maps slice arctic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, visualisation, arctic

I am developing earthquake visualization web-app for arctic zone using Google Maps JavaScript API. During the development I found Google Maps doesn't display map above approximately N85 degree, if you build Google maps in your site (on their [site](https://www.google.com/maps/@74.1491629,46.5047644,4260927m/data=!3m1!1e3) arctic displays correctly in satellite mode). It's fine if you don't work with arctic.

In my case this is a problem, because I have earthquake data above N85 to display. You can see my current situation on a picture below.

[image: Arctic problem]

Maybe someone already had same problem and knows certain how to fix it. I tried to set another projection for map (it also fix object distortion problem), but don't find high resolution tile for arctic. Hope there is another solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *problem* is that the projection being used [EPSG:3857](http://epsg.io/3857) is only intended to be used between 85.06°S and 85.06°N.

Comment: So I have to use another projection to display this zone? Is there any projection fit my task and Google maps (I read, it only works with rectangular projections)?